# Folder for 3rd party controls in Team Foundation Server 2008 source control

Tags: version-control, tfs

I am setting up a new TFS 2008 Server that we are going to migrate to (from VSS) and I am trying to layout the source control repository.

Having read the question [How do you organize your version control repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222827) I am trying to organise my folders in a similar way.

I want to create a top level folder called 3rd Party Tools or similar but from the Source Control Explorer it seems I cannot create a folder at the top level such as $/3rd Party

Do I really have to create a new Team Project for this?  Is there a blank template I can use rather than having to pick from the built-in Agile or CMMI templates?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think this is possible, but I can't find any official documentation saying so.  FYI - we created a team project called "CommonUtils" and then store shared libraries, etc. within it.

Comment: Yeah, I wound up creating a project called CommonTools and putting stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not create a second root under `$/`, you could create a general root "`{MyCompany projects}`", under which you would create:

- "{ThirdParties}`",
- "{Project1}`",
- "{Project2}`"

More details in this SO question: [Team Foundation Server Source Control Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381020/team-foundation-server-source-control-structure).

The general idea is to keep all related projects under one referential, sharing one common set of thirdparty libraries.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps the question was not clear. This is the structure I'm trying to create.  My question is can I / how do I create $/ThirdParty without making it a full blown Team Project?

Comment: Since I do not know that, I was proposing an alternative in my answer.