# Team Foundation Server Development Structure

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc, team-project

I'm a part of a small development team who are in the process of moving from Visual Source Safe to TFS2010.

I've been reading about TFS structure and came across a [very good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381020/team-foundation-server-source-control-structure:)

One thing mentioned in the above link which I'm not sure about is the Development structure:

```
- Development/
      - Trunk/
          - Source/
          - etc/
      - Branches/
          - Source/
          - etc/
```

I don't really understand the need for the `Trunk` and `Branches` as separate children containers to `Development`. How I'm reading this structure is that `Trunk` would branch from `Integration` (or `Main` if you use MS terminology) and `Branches` would then branch from `Trunk` (i.e. `Trunk` is the parent to multiple `Branches`).

If this is the case, I don't understand the advantage of the extra layer in the hierarchy. What seems logical to me (remembering that I've been learning this stuff for about a day) is that if you want multiple development branches, to have each development branch as a child of the `Development` container:

```
- Development/
      - DevBranchOne/
          - Source/
          - etc/
      - DevBranchTwo/
          - Source/
          - etc/
```

In the above structure (where `DevBranchOne` and `DevBranchTwo` are replaced with meaningful names), development branches are siblings and all branching from `Integration` (or `Main`). Given the above, my questions are:

1. Is my understanding of the intended use of the `Trunk` in `Development` correct?
2. If the answer to my first question is yes, what is the advantage of implementing such a hierarchy in `Development`?
3. Is the use of `Trunk` simply something that has been carried over from SVN (with which I have no experience)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, in the post you linked to it appears he has 2 "trunks", the Development\Trunk and Integration which is just another name for trunk in his context it appears.

Depending on your branching strategy you usually only want to have one "trunk" (or integration branch).

However, there are some scenarios where you might want multiple integration branches, such as if you are doing something like branch by feature, but you also have a concept of feature groups where the various feature branches need to be integrated together into the feature group, before being integrated into the subsystem's integration branch, which then will later integrate into the products main integration branch (aka trunk).

However, most branching strategies only require a single integration branch.

Comment: So using this model - the 'trunk' in Development would be used to consolidate features and feature groups from child branches, before merging them as a whole back into the parent Integration branch?

Answer (score 0):

I would not necessarily recommend using [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381020/team-foundation-server-source-control-structure) as a model.  It sounds like they're rolling up multiple feature branches into an integration branch ("Trunk") and then further integrating into yet another integration branch ("Integration").  This seems like a branching system meant to fit their existing workflow - while there's certainly nothing wrong with this system, it doesn't fit into my workflow, and you'd have to change yours to adopt.

In other words, you'd probably already know if you wanted a branch system like what's described in that question.  Your description of what you're anticipating is probably a good starting point:  multiple development branches and a single trunk (or main, or whatever you want to call it) branch.

If you haven't yet, be sure to check out the [TFS branching best practices](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) from the Visual Studio ALM Rangers.

Comment: Thanks for the link Edward, I have checked out the TFS best practices doc. The more I cover this topic the more I realise that there are many valid methodologies behind different branching structures. I guess I wasn't really understanding the justification for two integration branches.